# How to force wrapping all values of csv file with double quotes when converting from json?

Tags: javascript, json, csv, npm

My aim is to convert json object to csv. All values should be wrapped with double quote including integer numbers, text, etc. For instance, given the object:

```
{
    Make: 'Nissan',
    Model: 'Murano',
    Year: '2013',
    Mileage: '7,106'
}
```

The result of the conversion should be the line:

```
"Nissan","Murano","2013","7,106"
```

At the moment I'm using [json-to-csv npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-2-csv), but there I didn't find this ability. So I wonder if it's possible to do that with json-to-csv npm package? If no, what npm package is able to do this?

I've tried to explicitly set `options.delimiter.wrap = '"'`, but the wrapping is optional.

```
const converter = require('json-2-csv');

async function convertToCSV(jsonData) {
    try {
        let options = {
            delimiter: {
                wrap  : '"',
                field : ',',
                eol   : '\n'
            }
        };
        const csvData = await converter.json2csvAsync(jsonData, options);
        console.log("Convert Data --- completed");
        return csvData;

    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error("ERROR in converting data " + err.message);
    }
}
```

This code produses the line:

```
Nissan,Murano,2013,"7,106"
```

Comment: Taking a quick look at the json-2-csv manual it seems it is not able to wrap all values in double quotes. Why do you need it? Normally its only needed if you have special chars in the data and in that case it looks like json-2-csv is doing it by himself

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff I need to send csv-formatted data to queue and the consumer requires the quoted values (according to the task requirements). I don't have enough information about the consumer, so I can't rely on the theory that consumer is able to process csv with non-quoted values

Comment: According your code you return the content of csv data as variable. When the library is unable to do that, then do it manually by using replace(). For development paste your csv content into web gui or notepad++ or what ever you use and create the matching expression there.

Comment: If the object is simple like the one shown then consider [this example](https://tio.run/##LY3LDoIwFET3fMVNY9KSYPGRaKLBP1AXrtxxqTcErC1pCxvDt2NFl3Myc6bFAb1yTReWxj5ompQ1PoCtWijgnQCc8UkH4JfGezQ8@5LY0xGde4fGzuhO6CLZrNbbX6XRhPV3t8/Wqx1PxmOS/MzKD9F8rVpSQQ6oe/IivqXyhZ2YMxQnKNniPQfpqNOoSOQsrzPgjPF0ZGUqg70F15hapH@11SS1rUU8iGiaPg) that doesn't use any npm package.

Comment: @RobC seems like it's the solution I'm going to follow

Comment: @RobC sometimes you have to go multiple ways :-)